# SQL : If condition in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to check if table A has any entry THEN ONLY check table A column value is present in table B. If there is no data in TableA then just get data from TableB.

I want to have Exists clause for TableB select query if and only if there is data in TablaA else it will be just plain select query for TableB

Inner join wont work as there is possiblity that TableA won't be having any data, not even left join.

How do I do that in a single query?

something like this :

```
select Id from TableB where 
if( select count(*) from TableA ) > 0 then Id in (select col from TableA)
```

Comment: what? I cant understand. its too vague.

Comment: What do you want to do if table A is not empty?

Comment: correct me if my understanding is wrong, you want to
check Table A if have a record, if yes you will display records have a relation in Table A and Table B ? and if no records? what will happen? it will just display all records of Table B or it will display nothing? because if you just want to find if there's a record in Table A that is related in Table B, just use Join and it will get the records for you..

Comment: @wrecklez: Your understanding is right.check Table A if have a record, if yes you will display records have a relation in Table A and Table B. If no records,  it will just display all records of Table B.

Comment: @user1049021 can you see, if my updated answer help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select b.* from tableB b, tableA A
Where b.id = a.id
```

a simple join is enough for this.

Other way is using `EXISTS`. And put your conditions inside it.

```
select * from tableB b
Where exists
(Select 'x' from tableA a 
 Where a.id=b.id)
```

**EDIT:**

hope you need this.

```
/* first part returns result only when tableA has data */
select b.* from tableB b, tableA A
Where b.id = a.id
Union
/* Now we explicitly check for presence of data in tableA,only 
    If not we query tableB */
Select * from tableB 
Where not exists (select 'x' from tableA)
```

so, only one part of the query will return result, being the same resultset, `UNION` set operation, could make this done.

If at all, you want condition based results, PL /SQL could be a great choice!

```
VARIABLE MYCUR REFCURSOR;
/* defines a ref cursor in SQL*Plus */

DECLARE
  V_CHECK NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(*) INTO V_CHECK
   FROM TABLEA;

   IF(v_CHECK > 0) THEN
     OPEN :MYCUR FOR
        select b.* from tableB b, tableA A
        Where b.id = a.id;
   ELSIF
     OPEN :MYCUR FOR
       select * from tableB;
   END IF;
END;
/
/* prints the cursor result in SQL*Plus*/
print :MYCUR
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select b.id
from table_a a
,    table_b b
where a.col = b.id
and a.col_val = 'XXX';
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this may help you, but i know this is not the best answer,
in my own understanding you want to always display the records of your `Table B` And Check the `TableA` if have a record find their relations, but i think it does not need to count if you have a record in `Table A` or not,  if you use LEFT JOIN and put some condition to filter here's my example...

on this query All data from `TableB` will be displayed no matter if have a relation in `TableA` or none if have `TableA` and `TableB` have a relation it will return the value base on the relation, but if the record in `TableB` dont have a relation in `TableA` it will return a `null` value in that case you can use `WHERE` to filter what you want

```
SELECT * FROM TableB B
LEFT JOIN Table A ON A.id = B.id
```

if you just want to display All records of `TableB` with a relation in `TableA` add this

```
WHERE NVL(A.id,0) > 0
```